# JS, dynamic callback function (i.e. dynamic constants), click example

Tags: javascript, callback, ecmascript-6

My code is:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   elem[i].click(function(event) { alert(i); });
}
```

Unfortunately that does not work. Any idea how to make it alert the same `i` as the `i` in `elem[i]`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `let` for defining variable `i`. Unlike `var`, variables defined by `let` are block scoped. As a result, they won't be overwritten after each iteration.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   elem[i].click(function(event) { alert(i); });
}
```

By the way, when ES6 is available, it's generally a bad idea to use closures in this case. It's kind of overkill.

Comment: Thank you, a perfect solution.